# UTL_FILE_DIR on Oracle 11g SQL client

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, utl-file

Is it possible to set up a UTL_FILE_DIR path that points to a directory on a different server than the database server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely but the the directory must be visible and writable by the oracle user (or whatever user you are running the DB with).
[Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:241814624807) wrote an amazing write up on what you can and cannot do with UTL_FILE_DIR back in 2000 but a lot of the principals are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Share directory via NFS (samba if You usingn Windows) and create symlink do this directory in Your system and set UTL_FILE_DIR to it.